# Android:How to work on this type of listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

The data comes dynamically.i would like to set for this type of listview.I need an idea how to do it. Any one help me out guys???[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use either

- `FlowLayout` (see [here](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) and [here](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)).
- `StaggeredGridView` (see [here](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) and [here](https://github.com/chrisjenx/StaggeredGridView)).

Try them and see which fits your needs better.

Comment: thanx.i will check and get back to you

Comment: hi i have tried this : https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout but i am getting an error. see my update

Comment: @madhusudhan: well then you need to look into why you are getting that error ... an `InflateException` means there is an error in your layout file

Comment: already given 1+, I have one more problem , how can i use it for listview..please explain?

Comment: use what for listview ??

Comment: this is for static data,in my requirement  data comes dynamically.How can i show??

Comment: How can i increase the gap between buttons??